# Backbone asynchronous view instantiations

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would need to do something like this:

```
new app.view().done(function() {})
```

That's because I am setting the view element asynchronously in the initialize function and I need to use the element right after the instantiation.

If I do this it doesn't work:

```
var view = new app.view();
var $el = view.$el;
```

Because the view element isn't ready yet.

Again, I need something like this:

```
new app.view().done(function(view) {
    var $el = view.$el;
})
```

But I can't find any ways to do this. Would overriding the constructor help me with this?

Comment: Could you not add a method that returns the `$.deferred` object and then call that method after creating the new view?

Comment: No, because I would need to call this method every time, and this view is instantiated at a couple places :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1 - *Backbone.Events* - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kyleNeedham/C4jEQ/)

You could trigger an event after the `$el` has been asynchronously created like this:

```
app.view = Backbone.view.extend({
    initialize: function ()
    {
        // async setup the $el and then do the following after it is created
        this.trigger('el:created', this.$el);
    }
});
```

And then all other views can listen to this event and act accordingly:

```
app.anotherView = Backbone.view.extend({
    initialize: function ()
    {
        var otherView = new app.view();

        // Only fires once so only listen once
        this.listenToOnce(otherView, 'el:created', this.createEl);
    },

    createEl: function ($el)
    {
        //do something with $el here
    }
});
```

### Option 2 - *jQuery.Deffered* - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kyleNeedham/fAQRv/)

```
app.view = Backbone.view.extend({
    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.elCreation = $.Deferred();

        // async setup the $el and then do the following after it is created
        this.elCreation.resolve(this.$el);
    }
});

new app.view().elCreation.done(function($el)
{
    //do something with $el here
});
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but It would not work in my case, as is app.anotherView, the treatment I need to do after el is created is different each time. That's why .done(function() {}) is really great, because I can specify the code each time, instead of some generic code. But +1!

Comment: @Maxwell You can do different things with the first option i suggested, however if you check my updated answer you will see i have added "option 2" which uses `jQuery.Deffered()` method, which allows you to do `.done`!

Comment: !!!!! Genius! I love that second option, thank you so much! And sorry for the late answer.